# How to create dynamic table name in teradata sql

Tags: sql-server, teradata-sql-assistant

How can I create dynamic table name in Teradata?

I have created a dynamic statement with T-SQL but don't know how to do this in Teradata. For example in SQL:

```
DECLARE @MYTABLENAME NVARCHAR(20);

DECLARE @DYNAMICSQL NVARCHAR(1000);

DECLARE @CURRENT_MONTH_AND_YEAR VARCHAR(100);

SET @MYTABLENAME = 'TEST';

SET @CURRENT_MONTH_AND_YEAR = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 126),1,2),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 126),6,2));

SET @DYNAMICSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @MYTABLENAME +@CURRENT_MONTH_AND_YEAR VARCHAR;

EXEC(@DYNAMICSQL);
```

How can I write similar in Teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use a stored procedure to dynamically generate the SQL and then execute it.  Here's an example from the manual:

```sql
-- Create SP
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeeSalary (
  IN EmpName VARCHAR(100), 
  OUT Salary DEC(10,2)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE SqlStr VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;

  SET SqlStr = 'SELECT Salary FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmpName = ?';

  PREPARE S1 FROM SqlStr;
  OPEN C1 USING EmpName;
  FETCH C1 INTO Salary;
  CLOSE C1;
END;

-- Call SP
CALL GetEmployeeSalary('some_name', Salary);
```

There are other (cleaner) forms of returning results from dynamic SQL, this is just one way.

[Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/I5Vi6UNnylkj3PsoHlLHVQ/~VIB1PltfIm5X63Nc~aJTw)